# Which metric I should use for unbalanced binary classification model?

Tags: python, classification, precision, confusion-matrix, precision-recall

I performed a SVM on unbalanced dataset, splitting train/test in 70/30. The number of instances in training set are **1163993** of *class 1* and **234190** instances of *class 0*. For the test set i have **498699** instances of *class 1* and **100189** instances of *class 0*. The confusion matrix for SVM is displayed as follow:

[image]

What metric should I use to evaluate the model? It could be a solution to use the f-avg, calculating precision, recall and f-1 score for each class in this way:

[image]

and then calculate the f-avg by making the arithmetic mean of the two f-1 scores calculated for each class, as reported in the last row of the previous table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a probability evaluation metric here. In my opinion, using AUC-ROC (it is calculated using precision and recall) would be the right approach here, in fact for most binary classification problems.

Also refer [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/roc-curves-and-precision-recall-curves-for-imbalanced-classification/).